# Как правильно сгенерировать robots.txt Symfony 4?

Tags: symfony, symfony4, robots.txt

Подскажите есть ли готовое решение по генерации robots.txt для `Symfony 4` (если быть точным `4.3.11`)? Готовых бандлов практически нет, а те которые нашел - устарели и "завести" их у меня не получилось. Говорю про следующие бандлы:

- [miisieq/RobotsTxtBundle](https://github.com/miisieq/RobotsTxtBundle)
- [evheniy/RobotsTxtBundle](https://github.com/evheniy/RobotsTxtBundle)

А информации по самостоятельному созданию найти не смог. Могли бы (если есть таковые) поделиться готовым решением или подсказать в какую сторону рыть надо.

Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На мой взгляд, тут бандл будет лишним, решается в пару действий

`config/services.yaml`

```
parameters:
    robots.txt:
        - 'User-agent: *'
        - 'User-agent: Google'

services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
        autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.
        public: true

        bind:
            $userAgentParams: '%robots.txt%'
```

`src/Controller/RobotsTxtController.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

/**
 * @Route("robots.txt")
 */
class RobotsTxtController
{
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    private $userAgentParams;

    public function __construct(array $userAgentParams)
    {
        $this->userAgentParams = $userAgentParams;
    }

    public function __invoke(): Response
    {
        return new Response(implode(PHP_EOL, $this->userAgentParams));
    }
}
```

Comment: огромное спасибо, то что нужно!